Compositing Bokeh Blur node with depth map creates sharp edges
I'm trying to blur an image based on a depth map using the Bokeh Blur node, but I'm getting sharp edges in areas that are supposed to be blurred.
How can I fix this?



Here's my node setup:


Is there any reason not to use the Depth of Field of the camera ? I'm not sure why you are getting this edges.

This scene is not being rendered in blender, I just imported them into the compositor, so I can't use the scene camera.

I'm able to reproduce the same issue with a scene in Blender, even while following the official documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.1/compositing/types/filter/blur/bokeh_blur.html#id1.

The issue can be seen in this image in the docs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.1/_images/compositing_types_filter_bokeh-blur_example-1-render.jpg

That's crazy ! I think Blender doesn't handle well the solid edges of the depth map. It make sense to me, it splits the bokeh in 2 whereas it should add 2 different bokeh on top of one another.

I think I get it, long story short : you can't/aren't supposed to cheat depth blur in post-production.

Disclaimer : I came up with this answer by myself. It may not be totally true, or even wrong. It would be awesome if someone can contradict me and share more educated knowledge on that.
The summarize my answer : you'll have a lot of work to do if you want to add a depth blur (bokeh blur) in post-production. Your image and depth map don't contain enough information to create that blur.
Depth blur
As far as I know, depth blur is never achieved in post-production, it should happen at rendering (production). The reason is : a perfectly sharp image and depth map lack information to achieve a depth blur. Let me explain visually.
Let's say we have the following scene, a close out-of-focus object and a distant Suzanne in-focus.

The highlighted line will be the lightray we are gonna study, the edge between the front object and the background.
Without blur we have the following render :

Now if we add depth blur at render, we get :

As you can see, there is now a whole lot of geometry that we can see, here highlighted in orange. This information doesn't exist without blur. Seen from the top, the ray I introduced would look something like that :

The geometry only accessible with blur is highlighted in red. Rays are not correctly representing what's happening, but I think the point stays valid. Please only take that as a rough diagram.
What you lack
Your image won't be easy, as you have multiple overlaps between objects. In your zoomed example, here is in orange the area where we lack information for the gray background :

But that's not the only overlap. The stone is also obstructed by the wood. So we also lack information there (in blue) :

And you can add every other place in your render where 2 objects at 2 different camera distance overlap one another.
A very simple solution
The simplest of solution would be to use a gradient texture instead of the depth map. Any grayscale image that is smooth, with no sudden change of color.
A complex solution
That's quite a task but you could also

Separate your render in multiple layers (everywhere the blur is wrong)
Reconstruct manually the missing part (paintout)
Apply different blur to each layer
Merge them together

I'm not going into more details for now, but if you really want to do that and if I find the time, I'll edit my answer with more informations. Let me know.

Thanks. I was able to get an acceptable result by blurring the depth map a bit.
